# Postgres. Generate continuous series for multiple categories

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a table that looks like this:

```
update_date  start_date   end_date   category_1 category_2    value
2013-03-04   2013-05-11  2013-06-08     a1           b1        23
2013-02-19   2013-03-16  2013-09-21     a2           b2       112
..
```

Now i want to transform the above table to this format:

```
date   category_1   category_2   value   update_date
```

For each pair of (`category_1`, `category_2`) I want to have a continuous series such as `date` is `between start_date and end_date` for each pair of (`category_1`, `category_2`) and keeping the respective `value` and `update_date`.

For example, for (a1, b1) I would have:

```
date       category_1  category_2   value   update_date
2013-05-11    a1          b1          23     2013-03-04
.             a1          b1          23     2013-03-04
.             a1          b1          23     2013-03-04
2013-06-08    a1          b1          23     2013-03-04
```

and this table would continue for each pair of (`category_1`, `category_2`).

I reckon there'd be duplicates of values in date column but i'm OK with that as long as there are no duplicates of (`category_1`, `category_2`) pair.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - yes, i tried several approaches on using `generate_series()` but can't figure out how to `generate_series` per categories and then `join` them somehow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` function:

```
select
    d.d::date as date, 
    t.update_date,  
    t.category_1, 
    t.category_2,
    t.value
from 
    t, 
    generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') as d(d) ;
```

It works basically by taking each row from `t` and producing a set of rows, one for each day from `start_date` up to (and including) `end_date`.

Test at [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2f9a04f0155f91e496ced2aa916e80af)